# GraphView: rotating horizontal date labels, specifying a fixed size of the viewport and aligning the bullet points with the date labels

Tags: java, android, graph, android-graphview

This is a 3 part question.

1) First, is it possible to rotate the horizontal X values. Currently when I am trying to display all the days in a month on the X axis (4/1/2015, 4/2/2015, etc...) they will all bunch up and become unreadable. **Is there a way to rotate the X-axis labels so they are vertical?**

---

2) To setup the viewport, the documentation suggests to use:

> ```
> graphview.getViewport().setScalable(true);
> graphview.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
>
> // To set a fixed manual viewport use this:
> // set manual X bounds
> graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
> graph.getViewport().setMinX(0.5);
> graph.getViewport().setMaxX(3.5);
>
> // set manual Y bounds
> graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
> graph.getViewport().setMinY(3.5);
> graph.getViewport().setMaxY(8);
> ```

However, the `getViewport().setMinX(...)` function requires a double, not a date. **Is there a way to scroll the viewport to show 3-5 dates at a time?**

[image]

Code 2):

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) graphView.findViewById(R.id.graph);

DataPoint[] stockArr = new DataPoint[dplist.size()];
stockArr = dplist.toArray(stockArr);

LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(stockArr);
graph.addSeries(series);
graph.setTitle("TEST GRAPH");

// set date label formatter
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(context));

graph.getViewport().setScalable(true);
graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(data.size()-1); // Approx 28-30

graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph.getViewport().setMinX(firstDate.getTime());
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(lastDate.getTime());
```

---

3) **Is there a way to line up the bullet points with the Date labels?** I modified my X labels with the following code. However, even before the change it seems like the bullet points are not lined up. In the picture below, 1/1 should be the first point, 1/2 should be the 2nd point, and 1/3 should be the third point. Any ideas?

[image]

Code 3):

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(context) {

    @Override
    public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
        if (isValueX) {
            // show normal x values
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            // set time in milliseconds
            c.setTimeInMillis(((long)value));
            int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            System.out.println((mMonth+1) + "/" + mDay);
            // Return Month/Day
            return (mMonth+1) + "/" + mDay;
            //return super.formatLabel(newDate.toString(), isValueX);
        } else {
            // show currency for y values
            return super.formatLabel(value, isValueX);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

1) rotated labels are currently not supported. There is already an issue for that, but I can not say when this will be implemented. You can watch it here:
https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/293

If you want to implement it for yourself you will have do this at this point of code - it should be relativ easy:
https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphview/GridLabelRenderer.java#L934

2) The viewport needs a double and if you want to use Dates, you have to convert the date to the unix time epoch in millis via `date.getTime()`.

If I understand you, you want to display a timespan of 3 days at a time. So you have to set the number of horizontal labels to 3 and the viewport to a size of 3 days. Should be done like that:

```
graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(3);
graph.getViewport().setMinX(firstDate.getTime());
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(firstDate.getTime() + 3*24*60*60*1000); // + 3 days
```

Comment: Hi jjoe64. I implemented changes specified in your 2) response. The window does show 3 now and seems to be working great. I put a 3rd question if you can look at it. It deals with lining up the points with their labels.

Comment: the bullet points are at the position of your input data and are not aligned to the grid

Answer (score 1):

**Late, but adding some light to the matter:**

**1)** Although the issue for "[x labels rendered at an angle](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/293)" remains open, now it is possible.

Tested with *GraphView 4.2.2*. Assuming `graph` is your `GraphView` object:

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsAngle(90);
```

> In some case, an angle of `135°` allows to display the labels in a
>   more compact and elegant way.

---

**2)** Look at @appsthatmatter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28643746/4071001).

> If you go ahead with point **3)**, you must adapt the @appsthatmatter's answer acording with the last part of **3)**: *"And if you want to specify a fixed size of the viewport..."*
>
> ```
> graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(3);
> graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
> graph.getViewport().setMinX(getDaysSinceEpoch(firstDate));
> graph.getViewport().setMaxX(getDaysSinceEpoch(firstDate) + 3); // + 3 days
> ```

---

**3)** As you want to display the **days** in a month on the X axis (4/1/2015, 4/2/2015, etc...), I recommend you to use the number of days since [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), instead of milliseconds like the `java.util.Date#getTime()` returns. So there are no intermediate values ​​between the data to be represented.

This implies that:

- You can't initialize a `DataPoint` using:

  ```
  new DataPoint(date, value);
  ```

  Instead, you should use something like this:

  ```
  new DataPoint(getDaysSinceEpoch(date), value);
  ```

  Where `getDaysSinceEpoch(...)` receives a date and returns the number of days since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (Epoch) represented by this `Date` object. Using [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

  ```
  private int getDaysSinceEpoch(Date date) {
      return Days.daysBetween(new LocalDate(0), new LocalDate(date.getTime())).getDays();
  }
  ```
- You can't use `DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter`.

  Instead, you must implement your own `LabelFormatter`:

  ```
  graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DefaultLabelFormatter() {
      @Override
      public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
          return isValueX
                  ? getFormattedDate((int) value, "M/d")
                  : super.formatLabel(value, isValueX);
      }
  });
  ```

  Where `getFormattedDate(...)` receives the number of days since Epoch, as well as the pattern describing the date format, and return the formatted date. Using [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

  ```
  private String getFormattedDate(int daysSinceEpoch, String pattern) {
      return new LocalDate(0).plusDays(daysSinceEpoch).toString(pattern);
  }
  ```
- You should **not** disable the *"rounding of the bounds to nice human-readable numbers"* feature as [Use dates as labels](http://www.android-graphview.org/dates-as-labels/) suggests.

  Set it `true`, comment or simply delete this line:

  ```
  // graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);
  ```
- And if you want to specify a fixed size of the viewport, using:

  ```
  graph.getViewport().setMinX(...);
  graph.getViewport().setMaxX(...);
  ```

  You can't convert the date to the number of milliseconds since Epoch using `date.getTime()`.

  Instead, you must use the `getDaysSinceEpoch(...)` functionality described above.